# query array using mongo for C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following json

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("4f7ee46e08403d063ab0b4f9"),
"name" : "MongoDB",
"notes" : [
            {
              "title" : "Hello MongoDB",
              "content" : "Hello MongoDB"
            },
            {
              "title" : "ReplicaSet MongoDB",
              "content" : "ReplicaSet MongoDB"
            }
         ]
}
```

I am able to query a specific document in this manner:

```
db.collection.find({ "notes.title" : "Hello MongoDB"});
```

How do I go about creating the above query using FilterDefinition?
I am using Mongo for C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("notes.title", "Hello MongoDB");
```

the above should work for you.